# On click trigger change of state on another component won't work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I set up an on click function that should trigger a change of state in a separate component located in a different file. My `splash.js` file contains the component `Splash` which has a logo that when clicked, it changes from the landing page(Splash) to my Home. This is `splash.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Woods from './woods.jpeg';
import Logo1 from './whitestar.png';
import Logo2 from './orangestar.png';

export default class Splash extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            imgSrc: Logo1 
            //this.toggleShowHome = this.toggleShowHome.bind(this);
        }
        this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseOut = this.handleMouseOut.bind(this);
    }

    toggleShowHome(property){
        this.setState((prevState)=>({[property]:!prevState[property]}));
        //this.props.triggerClickOnLogo();

     }

    handleMouseOver() {
        this.setState({
            imgSrc: Logo2 
        });
    }

    handleMouseOut() {
        this.setState({
            imgSrc: Logo1
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id='Splashwrapper'>
            <img id='logoc' onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut} src={this.state.imgSrc} onClick={this.props.onLogoCLicked}></img>
                <img id='backg' src={Woods}></img>
            </div>    
        );  
    }
}
```

The on click function should change the state of `splash` in my `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Splash from './splash';

import Menu from 'components/Global/Menu';

export default class About extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            splash: true
        }
        this.logoClicked = this.logoClicked.bind(this);

    }

    //componentDidMount() {
        //setTimeout (() => {
        //this.setState({splash: false});
        //}, 10000);
    //}

    logoClicked(props) {
        this.setState({splash:false});
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.splash) {
            return <Splash onLogoClicked={this.logoClicked.bind(this)} />
        }

        const { children } = this.props; // eslint-disable-line

        return (
            <div className='About'>
                <Menu />
                { children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, my code doesn't do anything. How can I link the on click function in `Splash` to change the state of `splash` in my `App.js` file so it shows my home page?

Comment: Are there any messages in the console?

Comment: No, it simply does nothing..

Comment: Quite sure it won't matter, but maybe...
you are binding "logoClicked" with "this" both on constructor and on the props you pass, try to do it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in your `Splash` component. On the `img` you do `onClick={this.props.onLogoCLicked}` but when you use the component you pass in the props as `onLogoClicked` - note the capital L in clicked.

Consider using `propTypes` in your components, if a required prop is not there React will make some noise about it.

Comment: Wow, this had me going crazy and I can't believe I missed that typo lol. Works now perfectly.